# ACF for audio url in wordpress audio shortcode

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, audio

This **WordPress shortcode** plays an audio file for you and works great:

```
[audio src="http://XXX.mp3"]
```

In a specific post or page ,I want to give it the **url** of song using **Advanced Custom filed (ACF)** plugin:

```
[audio src="[acf field="sound_file_1"]"]
```

but It does not work and tries to open  *[acf feild"...* as the song url.
(**Note** that I have defined the url field using acf and tested it alone without audio shortcode and it works)

Comment: Have you tried with `[acf field='sound_file_1']` ?

Comment: @SallyCJ yes, it was the first Idea that I have tested

Comment: It's probably because WordPress doesn't support nested shortcodes, and the default `[audio]` shortcode also doesn't parse shortcode in the audio source (i.e. the `src` parameter). However, you can overcome that, by creating a custom shortcode - e.g. `[audio_acf]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent tested yet but I think can work, what I would do is create a function to create a new shortcode from those to doing this.

```
function new_shortcode() {
$urlmusic = get_field('sound_file_1');

echo do_shortcode("[audio src='$urlmusic']");
}

add_shortcode( 'audioACF', 'new_shortcode' );
```

Use [audioACF]

Comment: thank you, actually your answer needs a correction to work, I have corrected and worked: `echo do_shortcode(("[audio src='$urlmusic']");