# using wordpress acf shortcods in tables goes outside the table

Tags: plugin-development, advanced-custom-fields, table

I want to put some **audio** files in a html table using wordpress default [audio] shortcode and using ACF to take the url of song.
 because of using two nested shortcode does not renderrd in wordpress, I have done this using a costume shortcode and a function as it is asked in another question here:
[ACF for audio url in wordpress audio shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319702/acf-for-audio-url-in-wordpress-audio-shortcode)

and now this is my code:

```
add_shortcode('audio_nested',custume_url_callback);
function custume_url_callback ($atts = ''){
    $value = shortcode_atts( array(
        'my_feild' => '',
    ), $atts );
    $urlmusic = get_field($value['my_feild']);
        echo do_shortcode("[audio src='$urlmusic']");
}
```

now when I use it in the post contebnts it is OK, but when I use my shortcode in a table, the player does not appear in the table and goes on the top of post contents.
 but if I use the default [audio src="XXX.mp3"] in the table it works good and will be placed right in the table cell.
I have tested the **tablepress** plugin and other plugins for table and also I have wrote a simple **html table** but no change in result.
here you can see a screenshot of the problem:
https://pasteboard.co/HO9A2lw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some days and testing lots of solutions, at last I have solved the problem using wordpress audio php function **directly** in code instead of using `[audio]` shortcode and `do_shortcode()` function.
here you can find more detail and how to use it:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_audio_shortcode